# Use a variable within a SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need the outer select in order to save myself from repeating the additions done in the inner select.

Is there anyway to do this in one select statement? For example, could I set variables for s1 and s2?

Otherwise, for a long sequence of aggregations, I need several nested selects with lots of values being passed along unchanged.

```
SELECT
    s1,
    s2,
    s1 + s2
FROM
    (SELECT
        value1 + value2 AS s1,
        value3 + value4 AS s2
    FROM
        table1) a
```

Comment: You need separate `SELECT` clauses for each time you have dependencies between values. You can have them by using subqueries or `APPLY`, but there's no avoiding the need for separate `SELECT` clauses - because every expression within a single `SELECT` clause is evaluated "as if" they're all being evaluated in parallel. As such, no dependencies between expressions are allowed (within a single `SELECT` clause).

Comment: I'm just trying to get my query to work at the moment. Then I could post some code. :)

Comment: Well then, go and answer some questions elsewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t.s1, t.s2
FROM table1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value1 + value2 AS s1, value3 + value4 AS s2) AS t
```

Then you can use `s1` and `s2` in the `SELECT` clause as if they were normal table fields.

Answer (score 0):

`CROSS APPLY` is not really meant to use it to create something like a variable acutally, but it is very usefull to reach exactly this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(value1 VARCHAR(10),value2 VARCHAR(10),value3 VARCHAR(10),value4 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('a','b','c','d'),('e','f','g','h');

SELECT
    s1,
    s2,
    s1 + s2
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT
    value1 + value2 AS s1,
    value3 + value4 AS s2
) AS a
```

Comment: How would I add another level? Say, I wanted to use "s1 + s2"?

Comment: add another cross apply

Comment: @IanWarburton If you really have to deal with kind of data trees there is no easy going... It would help, if you give an example of data and structure and the expected output. In special cases there exist some tricks...